# My Ubuntu 20.04 appearance settings are mostly grayed out

Tags: themes, 20.04, system-settings, ubuntu-dock, gnome-control-center

I recently upgraded to Ubuntu 20.04 relatively smoothly. However, the dock is auto-hidden on the left side of the screen. When I go into the gnome control center settings and click Appearance I am greeted with the below settings.

It's a bit hard to tell from the screenshot; there is no theme selected, Icon size can't be adjusted, Show on is greyed out, and position on screen has three options: Left, Bottom, and Right. All three options can be selected but they do nothing. I can select a theme, nothing changes and the setting reverts to deselected if I change windows.

I have no idea where to begin investigating for this, and my searches just yield a bunch of results about how to customize the dock and how to enable dark mode. Maybe it's a video card thing? Everything else appears to be working fine.

[image]

Edit:
I just tried reinstalling gnome-control-center and it gave me the usual output:

```
$ sudo apt-get install --reinstall gnome-control-center
```

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 reinstalled, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/1,717 kB of archives.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
(Reading database ... 165754 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../gnome-control-center_1%3a3.36.2-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking gnome-control-center (1:3.36.2-0ubuntu1) over (1:3.36.2-0ubuntu1) ...
Setting up gnome-control-center (1:3.36.2-0ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for mime-support (3.64ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for gnome-menus (3.36.0-1ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.9.1-1) ...
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils (0.24-1ubuntu2) ...
```

Comment: Good idea! Unfortunately, that didn't change the behavior I see in settings. It did successfully reinstall though.

Comment: Did you reboot too?

Comment: I did not, I'm running at 0.25x speed today. Ill give that a whirl.

Comment: I'm back, no changes to the Appearance settings panel.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to figure out a workable solution by installing a gnome extension. Using this answer: [Install GNOME Shell extensions from terminal](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1152583/install-gnome-shell-extensions-from-terminal)

Text below in case the link goes away.

> Dash to Dock GNOME extension
>
> As seen at https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/307/dash-to-dock/
>
> Download the .zip file here
>   https://micheleg.github.io/dash-to-dock/releases.html
>
> Note: the name of the downloaded .zip file may be different than the
>   dash-to-dock@micxgx.gmail.com.zip shown in the unzip command shown
>   below. Adjust the command as necessary for the correct .zip name.
>
> See the manual installation notes here
>   https://micheleg.github.io/dash-to-dock/download.html
>
> Manual installation
>
> You can also obtain the extension in the form of a zip archive from
>   the release page. Look for the latest version supporting your shell
>   version. The extension can be installed by means of gnome-tweak-tool,
>   or alternatively by directly extracting the archive in the a directory
>   named dash-to-dock@micxgx.gmail.com inside
>   ~/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions/
>
> unzip dash-to-dock@micxgx.gmail.com.zip \ 
>   -d ~/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions/dash-to-dock@micxgx.gmail.com/
>
> Shell reload is required Alt+F2 r Enter. The extension can be enabled
>   with gnome-tweak-tool, or with dconf by adding
>   dash-to-dock@micxgx.gmail.com to the
>   /org/gnome/shell/enabled-extensions key.
>
> Note: DtD is not compatible with 19.04.
>
> rumor has it, that if you uninstall Ubuntu Dock, that DtD will work
>   with 19.04
>
> it also appears that the manual installation of DtD will make this
>   work in 19.04

I was able to download the `.zip` for dash-to-dock and extract it to the right location so `gnome-tweaks` would pick it up. The extensions section had the Dock to Dash entry and enabling it allowed me to move the dock around and see resize it as I expected.

I'm not sure if this dock behavior is a new feature of 20.04 or something on my system is broken, but I hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

You can fix this by terminal

```
dconf dump / > setting.ini
nano setting.ini
```

Search for `[org/gnome/shell/extensions/dash-to-dock]` in `setting.ini`
and change

```
multi-monitor=true
```

to

```
multi-monitor=false
```

save it and run this command in terminal

```
dconf load / < setting.ini
```

and you can remove `setting.ini` after this.

Comment: I upgraded from 18.04 to 20.04 and when I first opened setting.ini, I don't see this line _"[org/gnome/shell/extensions/dash-to-dock]"_ at all in the file. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I'm sorry for answering late, I edited my answer.

Comment: https://media.discordapp.net/attachments/499626925908688926/750825156695556177/Screenshot_from_2020-09-03_01-40-08.png?width=762&height=575

I research [org/gnome/shell/extensions/dash-to-dock] and I'm sure this line is exist. search again.

Comment: That's quite a convoluted way to change a `dconf` key. You can simply use the `gsettings set` command or `dconf write` command or the 'dconf Editor' GUI application to change the value.

Comment: yes so we can use simply this cmd in terminal
`dconf write /org/gnome/shell/extensions/dash-to-dock/multi-monitor false`